# how to refresh the list in after disabling item in adapter

Tags: android

this is the code.I have the list view with buttons , I am disabling item in list view in base adapter .after disabling the item in the list view the list is not refreshing. can any one know how to refresh the disable item in base adapter . now i need to change the list list view with disable item in list view. any suggestions please.

}

Comment: If you want to update the list on UI, call `notifyDatasetChanged()` on your adapter

Comment: i tried but not worked coz here am not deleting item i m disbling it

Answer (score 0):

The View object enabled/disabled does nothing. Try to change color of the item and make a custom "disabled" flag. In onLongClick set the "disabled" flag to true and change the way it is processed after that, i.e. clicking on disabled item does nothing.

Comment: can u plzz say it programatically